# Building report on CreatedDate for AccountTeamMember

Tags: reporting

Our client is trying to build a report on AccountTeamMember which should contain the createdDate of the AccountTeamMember record. I did a simple soql query on the AccountTeamMember records and the date fields' value are correct.

But when we do the reporting, that field doesn't show up or doesn't have correct value. Even after trying to create our own report type, the createdDate value is still the user's createdDate instead of the AccountTeamMember record's createdDate. Is there an approach to walk around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have some of the fields in Report on AccountTeamMember. This object is very different from other object in Salesforce. Currently you have Name and role field available only.

An [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpj0AAC) to have id field on report has been created already, you can create another one for created Date.

If you create custom report type, It will give you User information rather that AccountTeamMember.

Only Workaround for i could see is Creating custom Audit object which replicates AccountTeamMember. A somehow similar question already been asked here:- [Can we run a report on what account team members were added and by who?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13252/can-we-run-a-report-on-what-account-team-members-were-added-and-by-who)